# Cheap but comfortable way to get from Kingston, ON, Canada to Toronto?

Tags: budget, public-transport, canada, toronto, ontario

At end of August I have to go from Kingston, ON in Canada to Toronto. I'm looking for the cheapest way to get there, that has a least some comfort. So I don't want to hitchhike, but taking the train, take a car or even flying would be fine for me.

What are my options? How much does it cost? How long does it take? Where can I find further information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Train looks to be quite a good bet to me. It looks like Kingston is on the main Montreal-Toronto line, for which [seat61 has lots of details](http://www.seat61.com/Canada.htm).

I just asked [Via Rail](http://www.viarail.ca/en) for details for a random weekday in about a fortnight's time. There are 10 trains per day, a web special advanced purchase tickets start at $56 (but are mostly sold out for 2 weeks time, so book early!). Normal tickets are $65-$89, depending on how far in advance you book and how much flexibility you need.

Oh, and if you do take the train, try to sit on the left hand side as you head towards Toronto - you get some stunning views out across the rivers and lakes from that side!

Comment: Kingston is a major stop on the Toronto-Montreal line (all trains, including expresses, stop there).  VIA Rail has recently introduced a $39 non-refundable, internet-only fare between Toronto and Montreal.

Comment: VIA 1 does not cost much more than the regular fare when purchased in advance, and will provide you with bigger softer seats, a no-extra-charge hot meal (typically a choice of 2 or 3 proteins) and a staff who seem determined to get you completely drunk if they can (again, no extra charge), and free wifi. For a 3 hour trip, it's a good deal.

Answer (score 3):

I regularly travel in the Montreal-Toronto corridor. [VIA Rail](http://www.viarail.ca/en) is my preferred mode, for speed and comfort, but it can be very expensive depending on demand and proximity to the travel date. As @Gagravarr pointed out, the view is lovely along the river.

[MegaBus](http://ca.megabus.com/) also offers a comfortable service on clean double-decker buses with free WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Kingston is located at a nexus point of the major highways between Toronto, Ottawa, and Montreal.  As such, there are always people looking to ride-share.  One place these can be found is on the 'Kingston' [Kijiji](http://www.kijiji.ca/) site under the 'Community/rideshare' heading.